# How can you avoid hiding a base type member in C# when porting VB code originally using the Overloads modifier?

Tags: c#, vb.net, porting

Whereas [VB.NET's `Shadows` keyword has an exact equivalent in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8575465/279112), I've found elsewhere that the same is not true for its `Overloads` keyword, at least in the context of inheritance.  That being said, take the following code:

```
Public Interface IParent

    Property SomeBool As Boolean

End Interface

Public Interface IChild
    Inherits IParent

    Overloads Property SomeBool As Boolean

End Interface
```

At first glance, when porting the interface `IChild`, there doesn't seem to be a clear way to truly capture the exact meaning in C# without some sort of equivalent for `Overloads`.  If you try to do this:

```
public interface IChild : IParent
{
    bool SomeBool { get; set; }
}
```

Then you're liable to get a warning to the following effect:

> 'IChild.IsDefaultValue' hides inherited member 'IParent.IsDefaultValue'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

`new` is the exact opposite of `Overloads`.  Without an equivalent keyword, how can you be sure that this is ported correctly?

While this question covers classes as well as interfaces, interfaces by definition block you from emulating this through implementation.

Comment: Since the child property `SomeBool` has the same signature as the parent property, doesn't the `Overloads` modifier actually do the same thing as the `Shadows` modifier?  See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515037/shadows-vs-overloads-in-vb-net).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> **Shadowing and Overloading.** `Overloads` can also be used to shadow an
>   existing member, or set of overloaded members, in a base class. When
>   you use `Overloads` in this way, you declare the property or method with
>   the same name and the same parameter list as the base class member,
>   and you do not supply the `Shadows` keyword.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/overloads

So, when used for shadowing, `new` would be the equivalent.

Comment: In fact, `new` modifier in C# corresponds even more to VB.NET's `Overloads` than it does to `Shadows`.

Comment: In fact, shadowing concept does not exits in C#
Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575418/difference-between-shadows-vb-net-and-new-c/46773145#46773145