# How come sqlconnection.createCommand overrides return type of IDBConnection.CreateCommand?

Tags: .net, vb.net, inheritance

I'm creating a Data Access factory class. I have a base DataAccess class that returns an IDBConnection in GetConnection(). In the SQLDataAccess class it basically returns new SQLConnection(). What I'm wondering is how to override the return type to be a specific SQLConnection. I understand you can't change the method signature as discussed in [override property with a derived type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790607/is-it-possible-to-override-a-property-and-return-a-derived-type-in-vb-net). But they do this in .net with the DBConnection.CreateCommand() DBConnection returns a DBCommand and SQLConnection returns a SQLCommand by definition. How are they doing this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as how `SqlConnection` and others that derive from `DbConnection` do it they have a new signature that hides the one on DbConnection. Here is the partial code for DbConnection and SqlConnection.

```
public class abstract DbConnection {
    // ...
    public DbCommand CreateCommand()
    {
      return this.CreateDbCommand();
    }
    // ...
}

public class SqlConnection : DbConnection {
    // ...
    public SqlCommand CreateCommand()
    {
      return new SqlCommand((string) null, this);
    }
    // ...
}
```

You can use generics to accomplish this. There are other ways to do this though as it has been thought out before and there is more to it than just this as database implementations handle various items differently like placeholders for parameters, parameter types, functions that might exist in one implementation but not another, so your queries might have to vary too depending on the implementation. At first glance (we are obviously not getting the whole story here) this seems like reinventing the wheel so it might be better to research ORMs that abstract much of this for you.

```
public interface IDataAccess<TConnection, TCommand> where TConnection : IDbConnection where TCommand : IDbCommand
{
    TConnection GetConnection();
    TCommand CreateCommand(TConnection connection);
}

public class SQLDataAccess : IDataAccess<SqlConnection, SqlCommand>
{
    public SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection("");
    }

    public SqlCommand CreateCommand(SqlConnection connection)
    {
        return connection.CreateCommand();
    }
}
```

---

If you do not care about the specific implementation you are working with then I recommend you work with interfaces and forget the generics. Example:

```
public interface IDataAccess
{
    IDbConnection GetConnection();
    IDbCommand CreateCommand(IDbConnection connection);
}

public class SQLDataAccess : IDataAccess
{
    public IDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection("");
    }

    public IDbCommand CreateCommand(IDbConnection connection)
    {
        return connection.CreateCommand();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm working in VB.net. The best they have is that you can "Shadow" a method in the inheriting class.. Allowing for this. However, it doesn't actually override it. So if you have a variable of type DataAccess and assign it to an instance of SQLDataAccess, when you call GetConnection, it calls the method in the DataAccess class and not SQLDataAccess.

Comment: To answer your reinventing the wheel comment. Yes I know I'm reinventing the wheel but I'm dealing with ancient code and just trying to modernize it while making it backwards compatible. You at least answered how Microsoft did it. Now I'm wondering if I went DBCOnnection con = new SQLConnection(); con.CreateCommand(); Which CreateCommand method would it call? From what I'm seeing with Shadows in vb.net. It would call the DBConnection.CreateCommand() method

Comment: @dko - i edited the answer. If you do not care about knowing the provider (a good thing) then use straight interfaces. Have everything reference `IDataAccess` and have a factory to return the correct implementation. Your consuming code would then be working with IDbConnection, IDbCommand, IDataReader, etc.

Comment: I'll give you an thumbs up on the answer. However, I still can't properly recreate what Microsoft did. I'm going to run a test in C# to see if it handles it differently. Going dbConnection con = new SQLConnection. con.CreateCommand() returns a SQLCommand. If I have IDataAccess -> DataAccess -> SQLDataAccess. Run DataAccess da = new SQLDataAccess. da.GetConnection() runs the DataAccess.GetConnection(). From what I'm seeing in C#. Setting the base method to virtual should do what I want. I can't find an equivelant in vb.net