# Error due to concrete class and interface not having matching return types for IEnumerable<T> and List<T>

Tags: c#, list, interface, ienumerable

I have the below interface and concrete class.

I am getting an error of:

> 'DAL.Model.Audit.Categories' cannot implement 'DAL.Interfaces.IAudit.Categories' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.

Could anyone please explain what I am doing wrong here?

```
public interface IAudit
{
    IEnumerable<ICategory> Categories { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<IAuditAnswer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class Audit : IAudit
{
    public List<ICategory> Categories { get; set; }
    public List<IAuditAnswer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228359(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link, that helped explain why my assumptions were wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must respect the contract when implementing an interface:

```
public class Audit : IAudit
{
    public IEnumerable<ICategory> Categories { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IAuditAnswer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

In the interface the 2 properties are defined as `IEnumerable<T>`, so in your implementing class you should use the same type instead of `List<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can read this very useful article to know the reason:

[Variance in Generic Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228359%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> Unfortunately, strongly typed collections have drawbacks of their own..

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this doesn't work specifically is because `IList` is more specialized than `IEnumerable`.

In your head you (I would take a guess) that you thought `IList` implements `IEnumerable` so 'why can't I just use that?' and the real answer lies in [this stackoverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7996237/314661).