# How to implement IEnumerable<Animal> as IEnumerable<Monkey> in an interface implementation (covariance)

Tags: c#, interface, ienumerable, covariance

`IEnumerable<T>` is covariant. This means I'm allowed to do

```
IEnumerable<Animal> Animals = new List<Monkey>()
```

if `Monkey` derives from `Animal`.

Why am I not allowed to do the following, though?

```
interface ICage
{
    IEnumerable<Animal> Animals { get; }
}

class MonkeyCage : ICage
{
    IEnumerable<Monkey> Animals { get; }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this? If not, why?

Comment: Because `IEnumerable<Monkey>` doesn't match the exact signature expected by the interface. You can't do a covariant substitution for an interface. You can do something like `ICage<T> where T: Animal`, then have it be `IEnemurable<T> Animals { get; }`

Comment: @willaien so interface implementations always have to be exact matches? Is there a good reason for this?

Comment: @stuartd But Monkeys are Animals. Anyway I think I found the answer myself: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7996843/4961688

Comment: An interface can use an interface (to do the generic implementation), but in your example, you are referencing Animal instead of IAnimal?
So it is expecting you to provide an Animal class, not something that extends/Inherrits from Animal.

If you go back and change Monkey to inherit from Animal, then it will likely work.

Comment: @Baaleos - immediately after the first code sample in this question - "if `Monkey` derives from `Animal`"

Comment: @Baaleos Using IAnimal instead of Animal doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, because interface implementations in C# have to match the exact signature defined in the interface.

Some information on why this is the case can be found in this post by Eric Lippert:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7996843/4961688