# Interface implementations and return types

Tags: c#, generics, interface, enumerator

The `List<T>` class implements the `IEnumerable<T>` interface. It has a method `GetEnumerator` that returns a `List<T>.Enumerator`.

I have a class as below, which gives a compile error saying the return type of `GetEnumerator` doesn't match the interface.

```
public class InsertionSortedSet<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public struct Enumerator : IEnumerator<T>
    {
        // Required interface implemented
    }

    // Other interface methods implemented

    public Enumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new Enumerator(this);
    }
}
```

> 'Entities.Helpers.InsertionSortedSet' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'. 'Entities.Helpers.InsertionSortedSet.GetEnumerator()' cannot implement 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator'.

Given that `List<T>` seems to return it's own `Enumerator` class (not the interface) and yet it does implement the `Enumeration<T>` interface I'm confused, as I can't see what i've got different to that class.

### What's wrong with my setup that makes it fail, where `List<T>` works?

---

<sup>I want to return a `InsertionSortedSet<T>.Enumerator` rather than the interface as it avoids boxing, which I need to cut out.</sup>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's complaining because GetEnumerator() returns `IEnumerator<T>` for the `IEnumerable<T>` interface.  To satisfy, your type must return `IEnumerator<T>` (and an explicit one for `IEnumerator` as well).

But, many times it's desirable for a class to return a more specific type than the interface specifies, but interfaces don't allow for covariant return types like that.  So to do this, you can do what `List<T>` does and have `GetEnumerator()` return your specific enumerator, but you must also implement *explicit* implementations for `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` that returns an `IEnumerator` and for `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()` that returns an `IEnumerator<T>`:

```
    // This is your specific version, like List<T> does
    public Enumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new Enumerator(this);
    }

    // This is the one with the return value IEnumerator<T> expects
    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new Enumerator(this);
    }

    // Plus, it also expects this as well to satisfy IEnumerable
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
```

If you look at `List<T>` you'll see that it implements `GetEnumerator()` three times:

- Once explicitly for `IEnumerable<T>`
- Once explicitly for `Enumerable`
- Once with a very list-specific return

You could do the same in your class if you wish (which it sould like is the way you began) but if you do that you must explicitly implement `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()` and `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()`

If you navigate to the definition, you can see the other definitions in the object browser by selecting the different interfaces it satisfies (or by assigning a `List<T>` instance to an `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` reference and going to definition):

[image: Screenshot of Object Explorer]

Comment: @GeogeDuckett: I updated based on that.  List<T> implements `GetEnumerable()` three times, once with it's own List-specific Enumerator, and an explicit for `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Ahhh, i see. What tricked me is that right-clicking on `List<T>` and selecting `Go to Definition` doesn't show it. Where did you go to see all the `GetEnumerator` methods?

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: I was using a decompiler to peek in the .NET Framework assemblies, though you can also get the .NET source code online as well.

Comment: Thanks for adding to your answer. I'd totally forgotten about the object browser.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: No worries :-) I'm amazed at home much cool stuff is in VS that I forget about sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

To allow a class to be iterated using `foreach` no need to implement any interface. All what you need is implementing GetEnumerator method that returns your `Enumerator<T>`.

But if you want your class to support standard iteration interface `IEnumerable<T>` you may implement it explicity: `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }`

Comment: That helps for my use case, however the question remains; How does `List<T>` implement the interface, when as far as i can see, it does what i'm trying to do (returning a concrete type, not the interface).

Comment: public class List<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{ 
  public struct Enumerator : IEnumerator<T> { ... }

  public Enumerator GetEnumerator() { return ... }

  IEnumearator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }

}

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called return type covariance, more here [Does C# support return type covariance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709034/does-c-sharp-support-return-type-covariance)

This can be achieved by using explicit implementation of interface to return `IEnumerator<T>` and implement public method of same name to return Enumerator.