# Why can't I implement an Interface this way?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does C# support return type covariance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709034/does-c-sharp-support-return-type-covariance)

I'm not sure if I'm just being stupid...

If I have an interface:

```
public interface IMoop
{
    object Moop();
}
```

Why can't I implement it like so (I guess this would use implicit Covariance?)

```
public class MoopImplementor : IMoop
{
    string Moop();
}
```

Any instance of MoopImplementor would meet the contract specified by IMoop, so it seems like this should be ok.

Please enlighten me :)

EDIT: To be clear- since the implementing class returns something that inherits from the return type of the Interfaced method - I feel this should work. Specifically, a `string` IS an `object`. (and the same goes for any other inhertiance chain).

Comment: Because you are changing the semantics of the method?

Comment: You are not implementing `object Moop()`?

Comment: Since string inherits from object - it does meet the contract...

Comment: @Dave: The compiler is strict here. You need to make `Moop()` explicitely return an `object`, otherwise you don't implement the interface. That's not a problem, because you can simply return a `string` from the method, as you noted correctly.

Comment: Technically the contract also allows me to return Integer which your implementation does not.

Comment: Yes - I understand this. but WHY is the question :)

Comment: @kailoon no it doesn't.  The contract allows you to return an integer boxed as an Object, but not an integer.  Those are different.

Comment: @Dave: It's just the way the compiler works? What more is there to say?

Comment: No, it does not meet the contract. `'MoopImplementor' does not implement interface member 'IMoop.Moop()'. 'MoopImplementor.Moop()' cannot implement 'IMoop.Moop()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'object'.`

Comment: Regarding your edit `I feel this should work` - I feel people should give me free money, doesn't make it so.

Comment: I mean it seems logical, obviously.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

C# does not support *return type covariance* for the purposes of interface implementation or virtual method overrding. See this question for details:

[Does C# support return type covariance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709034/does-c-sharp-support-return-type-covariance/5709191#5709191)

C# does support *generic covariance and contravariance of interfaces and delegate types that are constructed wtih reference types for the type arguments* as of C# 4.

And C# does support *return type covariance* when *converting a method that returns a reference type to a delegate type whose return type is a compatible reference type.* (And similarly it supports parameter type *contravariance*.)

If this subject interests you, I have written a great many articles discussing various versions of variance that C# does and does not support. See

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/covariance-and-contravariance/

for details.

Comment: Holy hell, you weren't kidding - 11 blog posts on variance. There goes my whole afternoon :)

Answer (score 7):

Because the interface specifies that the method MUST return an `object`. A `string` may inherit from `object`, but the interface specifies a method that returns the much more generic type.

Keep in mind, though, there's nothing stopping you from doing the following:

```
public object Moop()
{
    return "Some new string";
}
```

Comment: but string IS an object.

Comment: @Dave: That's why we have specialized interfaces :p (I get your point in a way though)

Comment: Anywhere I use this as an interface - 'string' or anything else will meet the contract of "being an object".

Comment: @Dave: You're opinion is irrelevant. It's just the way it is. What's your point?

Comment: So - this is just compiler inflexibility? Because that's all the question was.

Comment: @Dave: Yes, and I can see like 5 comments on this page that tell you so which you seemingly ignored? **EDIT:** I wouldn't say it's inflexibility. The standard just doesn't support this.

Comment: @NiklasB. The question Dave posted is "why is it this way". I guess your saying the answer "it's just the way it is". To me that doesn't sound like a good answer. Maybe Jon Skeet will follow up as to if there is a reason for C# not allowing it.

Comment: @Naz I'd venture a guess that this is a pit-of-success issue.

Comment: @Naz: You have a point here. I was just trying to counter the OP's repeated comments along the lines of "but it *should* be different". Yes it should be, but there's no point in repeating this phrase all over again.

Comment: I'm just interested to find out the reason why if there is one.

Comment: @Naz: Yes, I'd be interested in that myself. Now let's no longer bother Justin with thousands of notifications and if necessary, continue the discussion in the comments to the question :)

Comment: @Justin - I appreciate your answer - However it's not quite a deep enough description of why this isn't allowed behaviour. Cheers :)

Comment: From a conceptual level, the argument should apply to method arguments.  E.g. an interface with `void something(string)` should be satisfied by `void something(object)`.  Of course, with the possibility of overloading, the match may become ambiguous.

Probably just one of those corner cases the framework developers didn't bother themselves.

Comment: @Dave To your question of "why doesn't the compiler do behavior X?" Because the compiler team didn't design, implement test, and distribute that feature.  It could have been that it was never considered, it could have been determined that it wasn't worth the effort, or it could have been technically impossible/unfeasible.  The real question is, "why should the compiler implement this feature" because without a strong compelling reason to do so it won't be done, "just because it can".

Answer (score 4):

A reasonable work-around:

```cs
public class MoopImplementor : IMoop {
  public string Moop() { ... }
  object IMoop.Moop() { return Moop(); }
}
```

This allows the public implementation on `MoopImplementor` to have the more accurate type while still fulfilling the requirements of the interface.

Comment: This has always bothered me. Specifically `IEnumerable` et al. But I guess we have to do what we have to do.

Answer (score 3):

You are not meeting the contract. However, you can do this with generics:

```
public interface IMoop<T>
{
    T Moop();
}

public class MoopImplementor : IMoop<string>
{
    public string Moop() { return ""; }
}
```

Comment: @asawyer : +1 for nice answer

Comment: @NiklasB. I agree, it's a different thing.

Comment: Sorry - this was not the question.

Comment: @Dave The answer is you are not meeting the interface's contract obligations in your implementation. Do it a different way.

Answer (score 2):

From the [C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx):

### 13.4.4 Interface mapping

> For purposes of interface mapping, a class member A matches an
>   interface member B when:
>
> - A and B are methods, and the name, **type**, and formal parameter lists of A and B are **identical**.

Note that it does not say anything about inheritance or convertability! The return type must be identical.

Comment: While that's nice, it doesn't mention anything about the rationale behind this :)