# Why I cannot implement an interface on a class replacing an interface with a concrete type?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, covariance

Why can I not do the following?

```
public class TestClass : TestInterface
{
    public ClassX Property { get; private set; }
}

public interface TestInterface
{
    InterfaceX Property { get; }
}

public interface InterfaceX
{

}

public class ClassX : InterfaceX
{

}
```

The TestInterface Property is readonly, thus can only return InterfaceX as per the contract.

However, I get this compiler error:

> 'TestClass' does not implement interface member
>   'TestInterface.InterfaceX'. 'TestClass.InterfaceX' cannot implement
>   'TestInterface.InterfaceX' because it does not have the matching
>   return type of 'InterfaceX'.

It does not have the matching type but it has a subclass of that type.

Comment: You messed up all inheritance in this one, InterfaceX != TestInterface

Comment: @Eric: I think I did not. Maybe using the same name for the type & the property is confusing. The type is ClassX and ClassX is InterfaceX.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709034/does-c-sharp-support-return-type-covariance) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338004/why-cant-i-implement-an-interface-this-way).

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to return the _derived_ type instead of the interface type?

Comment: @Dennis: Its not the same situation. I'm only declaring the getter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the spec offhand, but I'm sure there's one that explicitly states that return types must match *exactly* for interface implementations.  The closest I can find is 13.4.4:

> For purposes of interface mapping, a class member A matches an interface member B when:
>
> - A and B are methods, and the name, type, and formal parameter lists of A and B are identical.
> - A and B are properties, the name and type of A and B are identical, and A has the same accessors as B (A is permitted to have additional accessors if it is not an explicit interface member implementation).

If "type" above means "return type" that would indicate that the return type cannot change.

You could, however, change the return type and *explicitly* implement the interface with the right return type:

```
public class TestClass : TestInterface
{
    public ClassX InterfaceX { get; private set; }
    InterfaceX TestInterface.InterfaceX { get { return InterfaceX; } }
}
```

UPDATE

According to [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996127/the-return-type-of-the-members-on-an-interface-implementation-must-match-exactly) it seems to be a CLR limitation, not just a C# one.

Comment: The explixit reason is that the interface exposes a reduced set of the class functionality but I need it all at the class level to implement the logic

Comment: Then I would either use a _different_ property or use explicit implementation.

Comment: Note that Im only implementing the get, not the set like in the referenced question.

Comment: @SoMoS well, you ARE implementing `set` - it's just `private`.  There's no `set` accessor on the interface so you _can't_ implement it publicly.

Comment: "Only using get" is a moot point, the same specification rule applies.

Comment: @D Stanley: but you cannot do anything wrong with that design. You cannot use the interface to pass a type than cannot be assigned to the concrete class like the referenced question shows.

Comment: @SoMoS true, but that is a limitation of the language spec. Take it up with Lippert :) Also, see my answer :) You might like it.

Comment: Yeah, I do. I was arguing about the referendlced question only. Your approach seems good to me.

Comment: @SoMoS: So to clarify: in the linked question the poster wants something that (1) is not typesafe, and (2) even if it were typesafe, requires return type covariance. Your question is "ok, now I've made it typesafe, so that eliminates the first objection, so what's the problem?" The problem is that the second objection still stands: there is no return type covariance in C# or the CLR. Not because it is unsafe; it is perfectly safe. But because it's never been a high enough priority to implement, and all the compiler would do is implement the same code you could.

Comment: @SoMoS Think about it from a caller's perspective - if I call `InterfaceX` do I get a `ClassX` that I can call more methods on or a `InterfaceX` that I can't?  That's why the _explicit_ implementation allows both - the caller can specify _which_ method to bind to (and the compiler doesn't have to guess).  It's also (I assume) why methods can't be overloaded based on return type - how does the compiler know which one to bind to?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you want to expose a reduced set but you want all the functionality internal to the class -- that's not what you want to use an interface for. An interface should only be about your reduced set contract, not also magically function as a full set internally, not without another helper property.

But, there is a way around this limitation while still communicating the contract a little.

```
interface IExpose<IToolType> where IToolType : ITool
{
  IToolType Handler { get; set; }
}

class Expose : IExpose<Tool>
{
  public Tool Handler { get; set; }
}

interface ITool
{
}

class Tool : ITool
{
}
```