# Tuple List of Func List

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, tuples, func

I use .NET 4.5.1 - VS 2012.

I have several List, different entities types (Entity1, Entity2, .. EntityN)

```
   List<Entity1> list1 = GetData1();
   List<Entity2> list2 = GetData2();
   List<EntityN> listN = GetDataN();
```

Now, in my actual code, I use `LocalReport` (`Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms`) and `DataSources` like this:

```
   var rds1 = new ReportDataSource("data1", list1);
   localReport.DataSources.Add(rds1);
   var rds2 = new ReportDataSource("data2", list2);
   localReport.DataSources.Add(rds2);
   var rdsN = new ReportDataSource("dataN", listN);
   localReport.DataSources.Add(rdsN);
```

I would like use `Tuple` and `Func` like this:

```
        var dataSources = new List<Tuple<string, Func<List<T>>>> 
        {
            Tuple.Create<string, Func<List<T>>>("data1", () => { return list1; }),
            Tuple.Create<string, Func<List<T>>>("data2", () => { return list2; }),
            Tuple.Create<string, Func<List<T>>>("dataN", () => { return listN; }),
        };
```

**Usage**

```
 GenerateRDLC(dataSources);
```

**GenerateRDLC Code**

```
   public static void GenerateRDLC(List<Tuple<string, Func<List<T>>>> listFunc)
    {
            // ...CODE OMITTED...
            foreach (var t in listFunc)
            {
                var ds= t.Item1;
                var f= t.Item2;

                if (f != null)
                {
                    var list= f();
                    renderer.ReportInstance.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(ds, list));
                }
            }
            // ...CODE OMITTED...
    }
```

but not compiles for me (`List<T>`)

Problem `Tuple.Create<string, Func<List<T>>>("data1", () => { return list1; }),`

I have several types `Entity1, Entity2, .. EntityN`, not a single `T` generic type parameter

Any suggestions?

Comment: That's because `T` is not defined. To use `T` as a generic type parameter, it has to be defined somewhere as a type parameter.

Comment: I have several types: `Entity1`, `Entity2`, ...`EntityN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution** for me using `List<IEnumerable>`

```
List<Tuple<string, Func<IEnumerable>>>
```

**List< T >**

```
 List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

source code

```
  var dataSources = new List<Tuple<string, Func<IEnumerable>>> 
            {
                Tuple.Create<string, Func<IEnumerable>>("table1", () => { return list1; }),
                Tuple.Create<string, Func<IEnumerable>>("table2", () => { return list2; }),
            };

            ReportingManager.GenerateRDLC(reportPath, "MyReport", formato, new ReportParameter[] { }, dataSources);
```

GenerateRDLC method:

```
public static void GenerateRDLC(List<Tuple<string, Func<IEnumerable>>> listaDataSourcesYFuncGetDataForDataSources)
    {
            // *** code ommitted ***
            foreach (var tuplaDataSourceYFunc in listaDataSourcesYFuncGetDataForDataSources)
            {
                var dataSourceName = tuplaDataSourceYFunc.Item1;
                var funcGetDataForDataSources = tuplaDataSourceYFunc.Item2;

                if (funcGetDataForDataSources != null)
                {
                    var listaDatos = funcGetDataForDataSources();
                    renderer.ReportInstance.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource(dataSourceName, listaDatos));
                }
            }
            // *** code ommitted ***            }
    }
```

Comment: Issues if you use `dataSources = new List<Tuple<string, Func<IEnumerable>>>` in ***another AppDomain***: `AppDomain.Create`

Answer (score 0):

`Entity1`, `Entity2` and `EntityN` are all different types. `T` needs to be just one type, so the code cannot compile.

Even if all three share a common interface/base class, because `List<T>` is invariant, you cannot cast from `List<Entity1>` to `List<IEntity>`.

Comment: Not share common base class like ***http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554435/a-list-of-funcs-compile-error-with-generic-return-type-but-why?rq=1***