# Why can't an interface implementation return a more specific type?

Tags: c#, interface, language-design, overloading

If an interface specifies a property or method to return another interface, why is it not allowed for implementations of the first interface to "change" the return type into a more specific type?

Let's take an example to illustrate:

```
interface IFoo
{
    IBar GetBar();
}
interface IBar
{ }

class Foo : IFoo
{
    // This is illegal, we are not implementing IFoo properly
    public Bar GetBar()
    {
        return new Bar();
    }
}

class Bar : IBar
{ }
```

*I know* how to make it work, that's *not* my concern.

I can just either:

- Change return type of `GetFoo()` to `IBar`, or
- Explicitly implement the interface and just call `GetBar` from the `IFoo.GetBar()` method

What I am really asking is the reasoning for not just allowing the code above to compile. Is there any case where the above doesn't fulfill the contract specified by `IFoo`.

Comment: There's a third way, which is slightly more convenient than the above two.  You can implement the interface with an abstract class.  And then, in your "concrete" class inherit the abstract class instead of the interface.  Then in your "concrete" class, you can hide the base methods with the "new" keyword.  It's working decently for me.

Comment: I feel like BrainSlugs83's comment here is an answer as it provides a decent workaround.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Usually, I'd say that it would be a case of balancing the benefit against the added complexity of supporting such a feature. (All features take effort to design, document, implement, test, and then developers need to be educated about them too.) Note that there could be some significant complexities if you wanted to support returning a value type which implemented an interface, for example (as that ends up in a different representation, rather than just a reference).

In this case, I don't *believe* the CLR even supports such a feature, which would make it very hard for C# to do so cleanly.

I agree it would be a useful feature, but I suspect it hasn't been deemed useful enough to warrant the extra work required.

Comment: Jon i have a question? How do you write so much in 1 min?

Comment: +1 because the point on "...added complexity of..." but I'm not really sure it could be useful. After all an interface is a contract, if you need a method like that you can implement interface method explicitly and add another method with the _required_ return type so...what's that for?

Comment: @Adriano: You can, yes. But it's annoying that you have to do so, and explicit interface implementation has its own downsides and complexities. I avoid explicit interface implementation where I can, and if covariant return types were supported, it would be another place I could avoid it :)

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: It wasn't really *all* written in a minute. I did edit and add some more information...

Comment: +2 when I'm designing the contract of my application, I want to keep my code base reflective of the contract and not get confused with the concretes.

Comment: Jon, I don't dislike explicit implementation...I guess I can't see its drawbacks! :|

Comment: @Adriano: Consider one concrete class which derives from another which uses explicit interface implementation. If you want to override that interface implementation, but still use the original implementation, you have problems - you can't call `base.Foo()`, but casting to the interface ends up recursing back to your implementation. It also doesn't play nicely with `dynamic`.

Comment: Jon, you're a reference, as usual! :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guessed it was something along those lines. I'm gonna keep the question open for a while to see if anyone can come up with an example of where this feature actually breaks stuff. (Or if Eric Lippert comes and gives us the correct answer :)

Comment: Why would CLR support be required?  The compiler is already capable of generating code to implement interfaces which don't quite match the implementing members in other ways (e.g. if a class which implements an interface including a read-only property `Foo`, includes a public read/write property `Foo`, the compiler will generate a read-only property `Foo` which satisfies that interface).  Would there be any problem with the compiler auto-generating an explicit implementation which called the public member and returned its result?

Comment: @supercat: Hmm... I wasn't aware of the property example, but I suspect that there would be various subtle breakages involved in that sort of scenario. *Maybe* there wouldn't - but I'd argue that without CLR support it would be even more language design to validate that everything would work as expected.

Comment: *"I suspect it hasn't been deemed useful enough to warrant the extra work required."* - your suspicion is correct. This is precisely the rationale advanced by Eric Lippert at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709034/does-c-sharp-support-return-type-covariance/5709191#comment18406441_5709191, and over at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/357#issuecomment-98386283 a commenter tells a story of witnessing Eric arguing against the feature's implementation on these grounds at PDC.

Answer (score 8):

The feature you're asking about is called *"return type covariance"*. As noted [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Covariant_method_return_type), Java and C++ both have it, which perhaps makes it surprising that C# does not.

Eric Lippert confirms in the comments on this answer that this feature wasn't implemented because it wasn't deemed worth the implementation effort. (A previous revision of this answer assigned responsibility for that decision to Eric personally; he says that this is incorrect, and that if any one person is responsible it was Anders Hejlsberg.)

Regardless, there are now various proposals to add it to the language (see https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/357, https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/covariant-returns.md, https://github.com/kingces95/coreclr/issues/2), so perhaps it will get implemented in the next couple of years. Per those discussions, it doesn't sound like there are any profound reasons why the feature shouldn't exist in C# *in principle* - rather, it's just never so far been judged worth anyone's effort to implement.

Comment: The feature was added to Java a couple years before I was on the C# design team, so my opinion was not considered at the time. And while I was on the C# design team, to my recollection the matter was never under consideration by the design team. It would therefore be more accurate to say that *Anders* didn't think it was worth the effort. I don't think it's a bad feature, and I'd use it if C# had it. I agree that there are many more features that I'd make a higher priority though.

Answer (score 2):

It was not implemented, because they didn't feel like the feature would justify the effort. But there are good news.

This feature has been announced in a [post by Mads Torgersen in March 2020](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/), for the upcomming C# 9.0

> ```
> abstract class Animal
> {
>     public abstract Food GetFood();
>     ...
> }
> class Tiger : Animal
> {
>     public override Meat GetFood() => ...;
> }
> ```