# Can these class interfaces be implemented?

Tags: c#, class

Suppose we have the following definition in c#:

```
interface I1
{
    int num { get; set; }
    string name { get; set; }
}

interface I2
{
    I1 GetValue();
    void SetValue(I1 value);
}
```

If the interfaces are implemented like this:

```
public class C1 : I1
{
    public int num { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class C2 : I2
{
    public C1 GetValue()
    {
        C1 c1 = new C1();
        c1.num = 2;
        c1.name = "AnyName";

        return c1;
    }

    public void SetValue(C1 value)
    {
        C1 c1 = new C1();
        c1.num = value.num;
        c1.name = value.name;
    }
}
```

There will be a Compiler Error CS0738 for public C1 GetValue(): 'C2' does not implement interface member 'I2.GetValue()'. 'C2.GetValue()' cannot implement 'I2.GetValue()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'I1'

In another word, Compiler doesn't regard C2 is implementing I2.GetValue() because C2.GetValue() returns C1 data type rather than I1.

There will also be another Compiler Error CS0535, stating I2.SetValue(I1 value) interface method is not implemented because C1 is not I1 in C2.SetValue(C1 value).

Then, how to implement GetValue() and SetValue() of I2 interface?

Comment: If `C2.GetValue()`'s return type were `I1` it could still return a `C1` just like it is now because a `C1` is an `I1`; that's the whole point of an `interface`.  You'd need to change the accessibility of `I1` and `C2` to be the same, though, to avoid an inconsistent accessibility error.

Comment: Add `public` to `interface I1` or remove `public` from `public class C2 : I2`.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what implementing the interface means. I2 has `I1 GetValue();` meaning that any class implementing the interface should declare `public I1 GetValue() { }`, or an explicit implementation with the return type I1. You can't change the return type here. It has to match the interface.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The return type of the members on an Interface Implementation must match exactly the interface definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996127/the-return-type-of-the-members-on-an-interface-implementation-must-match-exactly)  See also [Why can't an interface implementation return a more specific type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10796650/150605)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an explicit implementation. It is fairly simple to do

```
public class C2 : I2
{
    public C1 GetValue()
    {
        C1 c1 = new C1();
        c1.num = 2;
        c1.name = "AnyName";

        return c1;
    }

    I1 I2.GetValue() => GetValue();
}
```

This tells the compiler that `GetValue()` actually implements the interface in `C2`.

Comment: Thank you! There is a another method in I2, say void SetValue(I1 value). When we implement it in C2: public void SetValue(C1 value) ();  there will be a compiler error CS0535, stating SetValue() interface method is not implemented because C1 is not I1. How to get around this problem?

Comment: @VBird why do you keep trying to change the method signature to a concrete implementation of I1? Are you looking for generics?

Comment: @VBird - Again you do an [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation)

Comment: @ProgrammingLIama Yes and no. I don't want to change the defined interface, including its accessibility, if possible. However, for public void SetValue(C1 value) in C2, it seems I have to make I1 public, right?

Comment: @VBird - usually it is a bad idea to do so, but in this case I recommend [edit]ing the question to _add_ the request for `SetValue()` in order to answer properly.

Answer (score 1):

The error and [its documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0738) are pretty clear: change the return type of `C2`'s `GetValue()` method to return `I1` instead of `C1`. [Example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxAJwK7wCYgNQB8ACATAIwCwAUBQG4TIAEUhdAvHQBQCShAlHTAKYB3OgGFCbbgG5qtBsRYNCAOgDi/BADUIAG1T8J08vmIBONlGJKYqMFIrGzFqxDD87lIwGYGMBP2QAZhAAxvx0HGTkAN4UdHE+CHw2dFF0AObqknQAzpl0AL6x8cYADHwuYakZCFm5NQUUhR743rB+gSFhXBQx5PHh8mqaOnoGjRT23kSi8iADPUVxLQlJYCnpeXVZTf3LpeWu69W1eU1Nk3TTYnRz3dGLl94RdENauvrcD739/SLywfJWAJhH8xn0fnEAVZkqxCIYIZDLDAKgoAEQAQRgAE8AHIVVGGB67ADsdAB8PiZyAA===).