# How can inheritance be reasonable without covariance? (C#)

Tags: c#, inheritance, covariance

I'm quite new to C# but I have quite good C++ knowledge. From C++ I'm used that something like this works:

```
class Base1 {};
class Derived1 : Base1 {};
class Base2 {
   Base1 foo();
};
class Derived2 {
   Derived1 foo();
};
```

which I know under the term Covariance. The piece of code might miss something but I hope you get what I want to say.
As I tried to produce something like that in C# with override and stuff, the Compiler complained that the type had to be the same. like this:

```
class Base1 {};
class Derived1 : Base1 {};
class Base2 {
   Base1 foo();
};
class Derived2 {
   Base1 foo();
};
```

Might that lead to any problems?
Of course as I am the programmer of function foo I can assure there will always be a Derived1 returned. But whoever calls my function doesn't know that.

I have a project in which I have some Manager classes, for which I wanted to use an Interface IManager (it's my own class, not any from .NET if there exists any with that name), because they all have to implement a method Load() for example. Load() always returns a an Object, that is managed by that certain Manager.
If every Manager implements IManager, all of them would get the Interface

```
ManagableObject Load();
```

Is that good, bad? Or even better, is there any workaround?

I also read that it worked with templates, but only like this I guess:

```
List<Base1> myList;
myList.push_back(new Derived1());
```

Or can I use List as return type in Base1 and List in class Derived2? That would be ok too.

Thanks and best regards,
Expecto

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your first set of class definitions (apart from requiring method implementations) - so I think you might be missing something in your explanation. What compiler error do you get?

Comment: C# actually supports covariance in various places; however _covariant return values_ are not supported, which I believe is what you're after here. Your samples are also currently broken with regards to showing the actual problem.

Comment: @RJLohan in English it would be sth like: "The return value has to be ManagableObject to match the overwritten method IManager.Load()"

Comment: @cwan yes, I meant the return value, but I thought I made that clear, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I meant: [Does C# support return type covariance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709034/does-c-sharp-support-return-type-covariance) but I didn't know to look for the term return type covariance

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your method using the new keyword.

```
 class Derived2 {
  new Derived1 foo();
};
```

Comment: Use the new modifier to explicitly hide a member inherited from a base class. To hide an inherited member, declare it in the derived class using the same name, and modify it with the new modifier. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vclrfnew_newmodifier) it used when class base { void test(){}} class derived:base{ new void test(){}} (new is used only to hide base method, without new keyword compiler produces only warning message but code is compilable and executable)