# Interface referencing another interface but class referencing another class in C#

Tags: c#

I have a very simple question, but I haven't had this problem before.

Take a look at this code:

```
interface IFoo
{
    IBar MyBar { get; }
}

interface IBar
{
    String Test { get; }
}

class Foo : IFoo
{
    public Bar MyBar { get; set; }
}

class Bar : IBar
{
    public String Test { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that Foo doesn't implement IFoo since it returns Bar rather than IBar. But I don't see the problem since Bar is implementing IBar. Do I miss something?

I want my application to use the class Foo but expose IFoo to other parts of the solution.

This is a way around it, but it seems like an ugly solution:

```
class Foo : IFoo
{
    public Bar MyBar { get; set; }
    IBar IFoo.MyBar { 
        get { return this.MyBar; }
    }
}
```

Is this the way to go, or is it a better way?

Comment: `Bar` is an `IBar`, but `IBar` is not a `Bar`.

Comment: This is called return type covariance and according to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709034/does-c-sharp-support-return-type-covariance) C# and the CLR doesn't support it.

Comment: The "ugly way around" (also known as the explicit interface implementation) is indeed the only way around this issue in C#. In fact, that's part of the reason the feature exists in the first place.

Comment: I think your solution (explicit interface) is the preferred way I'd go. Another option since you only have getters is to use `out` generics: `interface IFoo<out T> where T : IBar { T MyBar { get; } }` then you can assign foos like: `IFoo<IBar> f = new Foo();`, but that kind of sucks because you have this useless generic floating around all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
interface IFoo<out B> where B:IBar
{
    B MyBar { get; }
}

interface IBar
{
    String Test { get; }
}

class Foo : IFoo<Bar>
{
    public Bar MyBar { get; set; }
}

class Bar : IBar
{
    public String Test { get; set; }
}
```

This will only work in the case that `B` is in an output position (for obvious reasons, if you think about it long enough).

Answer (score -1):

> The problem is that Foo doesn't implement IFoo since it returns Bar rather than IBar. But I don't see the problem since Bar is implementing IBar. Do I miss something?

Yes. You're misinterpreting the contract of the IFoo interface. The contract is simple:

One property named MyBar, that has a getter, and **has a return type of IBar.** The contract isn't that it returns an object that is of type IBar, it's that the return type is type IBar.

This is standard. Try implementing the `ICloneable` interface, which has a single method, `Clone()`, with a return type of `object`. Implementing this interface means you must implement a method with a return type of `object`, no matter what. Even if you'd rather be a bit more specific, any other return type won't qualify.

The way around it you suggested is one of the right ways to go about it - having an IBar property that returns the Bar property. Or, y'know, you *could* just have an IBar property and set it to a Bar instance, since that's perfectly valid, and then work with your IBar object through the IBar contract. That would help with decoupling.