# Return a subclass of abstract return type?

Tags: c#, inheritance

My project is structured the following way:

```
// Abstract class
public abstract class Job
{
    public abstract JobResult Run();
}
public abstract class JobResult { }

// Concrete implementer
public class Job1 : Job
{
    public override Job1Result Run() { }
}
public class Job1Result : JobResult { }
```

Each concrete job inherits from Job and implements the method Run which returns a concrete class of JobResult.

However when I do this I get the compiler error:

> Job1.Run()': return type must be JobResult to match overridden member
> Job.Run()

Is it really not possible to return an inheriting object of the return type when overriding an abstract method?

Comment: Try changing it to `public override Job1Result Run()` ?

Comment: @McAdam331
Sorry I had that in my project but forgot to include it in my question here. I've updated it to include it. Still got the error though.

Comment: This is called return type covariance. It is not supported. Overrides must match the signature, generic constraints, *and* return type.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709034/does-c-sharp-support-return-type-covariance

Answer (score 5):

This is the whole concept of inheritance. Returning parent classes is considered a feature here. Nothing stops you however from returning a `Job1Result` in `Job1`

```
public JobResult Run()
{
  return new Job1Result();
}
```

Then the caller of Job1.Run() will have to know the correct return type and cast it to access `Job1Result` methods which are specific to that class

Comment: But then you will need always convert returning value from `JobResult` to `Job1result`

Comment: Not if you don't need to access anything special from Job1Result

Answer (score 3):

You could make `Job` [generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx):

```
public abstract class Job<TResult> where TResult : JobResult
{
    public abstract TResult Run();
}

public class Job1 : Job<Job1Result>
{
    public override Job1Result Run()
    {
         //
    }
}
```

Comment: While I like this solution I'm pretty sure I cannot use it since Entity Framework doesn't allow generic classes to be used as entities.
Correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: @JensOlsen112: I've never used Entity Framework before, but `Job1` is technically not a generic class, it just inherits from one.

Comment: Note that such approach will create sibling classes for each concrete type which generally not what one expect/wants with inheritance: `Job1 : Job<Job1Result>` and `Job2 : Job<Job2Result>` are not related to each other as there is no common parent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, I hope it can help you.

```
public interface IEvent
{
    Type GetEventType();
}


public abstract class AEvent<A>: IEvent where A: struct
{
    public Type GetEventType()
    {
        return typeof (A); // return sub struct type
    }
}
```