# Inheriting an interface with a refined return type

Tags: c#, inheritance

If I have

```
interface Parent{}
interface Child : Parent {}
interface MyInterface {
  Parent P {get;}
}
```

why doesn't

```
class MyClass : MyInterface {
  public Child P {get; }
}
```

typecheck, but

```
class MyClass : MyInterface {
  private Child C {get; set;}
  public Parent P {get { return C; }}
}
```

does?

Is there any way the two can behave observably different behaviour (minus that extra null check that would clutter the code a little before the attempted cast)?

I could use generics for this, and use

```
interface MyInterface<T> where T : Parent {
  T P {get;}
}

class MyClass : MyInterface<Child> {
  Child P {get;}
}
```

but I feel this would be a hack as it clutters the definition of the interface which will have to be explicitly set by all inheritors, and restrics the inheritors to a single subtype with seemingly little gain.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66748/discussion-on-question-by-martijn-inheriting-an-interface-with-a-refined-return).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your questions:

> why doesn't [x] typecheck, but [y] does?

Simply because C# (and the CLR) [don't support return type covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5709191/215380). (Eric Lippert is the best source you can get for an answer to a question like "Why doesn't C# do X?")

> Is there any way the two can behave observably different behaviour?

No. You're correct in thinking that this *should* meet the contract.

A property getter that returns a `Child` theoretically meets the "returns a `Parent`" contract.

However, the fact remains that C# (and the CLR) don't support this. You know it meets the "returns a `Parent`" contract, but you can't tell C# that.

---

As an alternative implementation to your second example, you could use *explicit interface implementation*:

```
class MyClass : MyInterface
{
    Parent MyInterface.P { get { return this.P; } }
    public Child P { get; set; }
}
```

Implemented like this,

- whenever you use an instance of `MyClass`, the contract you see and can use is that it can accept or return a `Child`
- whenever you cast that instance to `MyInterface`, the contract you can see and use is only that it can return a `Parent`.

Edit: What this gains you over your working example is that if `P` is actually a sensible property name (that makes sense for both the `Parent` property in the interface and the `Child` property in the implementation), you can use it for both.