# Why can't a derived class override base class' interface type abstract property with a type that extends that interface?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

In the following code, compiler complains about B not implementing `TestProperty` of abstract class `A`. `ITest2` is derived from `ITest1` so it implements everything `ITest1` has. Why is this not possible?

```
public interface ITest1 { }
public interface ITest2 : ITest1 { }

public abstract class A
{
    public abstract ITest1 TestProperty { get; set; }
}

public class B:A
{
    public override ITest2 TestProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you are going to down-vote so quickly, can you at least care to explain?

Comment: What you are asking for is called covariance.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709034 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Inheritance_in_object_oriented_languages

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This wouldn't be safe since you could do:

```
interface ITest3 : ITest1 { }
public class Test3 : ITest3 { }

A b = new B();
b.TestProperty = new Test3();
```

however `Test3` does not implement `ITest2` as required by `B`.

Comment: To put it another way: Every dog is an animal, but not every animal is a dog.

Comment: Oh I see, with your example, it makes much more sense now. +1 for that.

Answer (score 2):

Make A class generic

```
Public abstract class A<TTest>
    Where TTest : ITest1
 {
    Public abstract TTest TestProperty {get; set;}
 }

 Public class B : A<ITest2>
 {
 ....
 }
```

Comment: That's what I had initially, I wanted to make the class non-generic.