# Return concrete type in abstract class

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class

We have an abstract class BaseClass (note generic arg!) with a method called me.
Me returns this.

If we use Me in the concrete classes we will get a return type object. 
Then we have to cast the result of Me to the type we originally are working with.

How can we achieve that Me returns the actual type of this? In this example type A?

```
public abstract class BaseClass<TIdentifier>{
 public virtual object Me{ get { return this; } }
}

public class A: BaseClass<long>
{

}

public class B: BaseClass<long>
{

}

public class controller{
   public void SomeMethod(){
       var a = new A();
       var b = new B();

       var aObject = a.Me; // this will be of type object
       var aObjectCasted = (A)aObject; // cast to original

       // How I want it
       var aConcrete = a.Me; // this returns type a
   }
}
```

**Update**

Since some people really, desperately (wink:-)) wish to understand what I'm actually trying to do.

With NHibernate we are doing this:

```
var result = Session.Get<A>(idToLookUp);
```

In some cases it happens that result isn't of type A but is of type AProxy, due to laze loading etc. Now if we want to cast result to something else: we will get an invalidcastexception because the actual type of result isn't A but AProxy. And that type can't be casted. We can only cast type A to the other type.

A workaround for this is described here: http://sessionfactory.blogspot.be/2010/08/hacking-lazy-loaded-inheritance.html. That's where the Me property in the above examples comes in.

So to get result of type A and not of type AProxy we now have to do this:

```
var result = (A)Session.Get<A>(idToLookUp).Me;
```

Note we have to cast me back to type A if we want to get to read and know the property of result.

My question: can we get rid of the casting and adjust the Me property so we instantly return the concrete type?

Hope it's clear now.

Comment: Why would you need to do this? You can already assign as follows: `object a = new A();` because the base class of all classes is `System.Object`.

Comment: Don't search after the why. It's a base example based on code in our company. It's reason is more complex: nhibernate bug: see http://sessionfactory.blogspot.be/2010/08/hacking-lazy-loaded-inheritance.html

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your code.. you're trying to get a property `Me` by calling it like a method `A.Me()`? That alone doesn't work, first off you can't call it like a method, and second off its not static so doing `A.Me` wouldn't work either.

Comment: @Mike, it was a typo. Indeed it's a property and it is beeing called as a propetry. But there is no reason why this should be static. A.Me works just fine (if called within a method which I forgot here)

Comment: You are calling Me from the Type A.Me, not the instance a.Me. If you need to call it from Type it needs to be static. Probably you meant instance, better update the question.

Comment: @CarbineCoder, once again another typo. Changed it. Thanks

Comment: Again... the question is not fully correct. Cant you just say Aconcrete = a? because if you say var a = new A() it will assume of type A() not Base type. Dont use var for declaration in the question, you probably should create a like this - `BaseClass<TIdentifier> a = new new A();` then `a.Me` method makes sense

Comment: See my first comments on toadflakz. This is an example based on a solution for a nhibernate problem. The scope is much bigger and complexer than this simple example. The above code is to make it comprehensive what is actually happening and what we are trying to improve, if possible.

Comment: I understand your point,  but the `var a` declaration misleads your intention. You dont have a problem when you say `var a` only when you say `BaseClass<TIdentifier> a` you can ask this question. Hence lot of people answering this question are confused.

Comment: Since I do understand some people are confussed I've added some explanation about the case, hope it makes a lot more clear.

Comment: Not being able to change A and B will most likely cause problems. You might have to access the object's properties and methods dynamically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use an interface on your derived classes:

```
public interface IStrongTypedMe<T>
{
    T Me();
}
```

Your derived classes would become:

```
public class A: BaseClass<long>, IStrongTypedMe<A>
{
    public new A Me()
    {
        return base.Me() as A;
    }
}
```

This is assuming you can change `A`, of course.

**Update:**

I understand the issue now (only had time to read the linked article now).

Try using an extension method to do the casting for you like this:

```
    public static TReturnType As<TReturnType,TIdentifier>(this BaseClass<TIdentifier> proxyObject)
        where TReturnType : class
    {
        return proxyObject.Me as TReturnType;
    }
```

And you'd use it like:

```
var result = Session.Get<A>(idToLookUp).As<A,long>();
```

No changes to `A` or `B` required.

Comment: Fixed - TReturnType specified as class.

Comment: Based on your suggestion I've implemented a solution. I've added an interface to BaseClass so I don't have to pass TIdentifier to my extension method. So now I can just say var result = Session.Get<A>(idToLookUp).As<A>();

Answer (score 6):

You can change the return type of this property to the definition of parent class

```
public abstract class BaseClass<TIdentifier> 
{
     public virtual BaseClass<TIdentifier> Me{ get { return this; } }
}
```

If you want to return exactly the same class you can make some workaround by adding the result type in the generic type parameter

```
public abstract class BaseClass<TIdentifier, TMe>
    where TMe : BaseClass<TIdentifier, TMe>, new()
{
    public virtual TMe Me { get { return (TMe)this; } }
}

public class A : BaseClass<long, A>
{

}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is the closest you can get

Comment: That will return type of baseclass and not a return type of A.

Comment: This is also a possible solution for a lot of people. It's a correct and working one. However for our specific case: we cannot/may not edit A or B so we can't add the result type in the generic type parameter since we have to edit A and B to. I gave you an upvote because this is also a good working suggestion for some people with the same sort of problem

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, C#, [unlike Java](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/covariant_return_types_in_java), [does not support return type covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709034/does-c-sharp-support-return-type-covariance). Otherwise you could just override the property `Me` in the subclasses like this to get what you want:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<TIdentifier> {
    public virtual object Me { get { return this; } }
}

public class A: BaseClass<long>
{
    public override A Me { get { return this; } } // wont work in C#
}

public class B: BaseClass<long>
{
    public override B Me { get { return this; } } // wont work in C#
}
```

Mikhail Neofitov provides a good workaround though.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Unfortunataly we cannot/may not change A or B so overriding may not be done. However I gave you an upvote because this can also be the correct solution to some people on this matter.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be clear, this wont work in C#, it's just an example of how this *could* be done, *if* the C# language would support return type covariance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do something like this:

```
var aObject = A.Me();
```

`Me` will need to be a static method.

1. A static method **doesn't** have a `this`.
2. If your **not** using a static method, you have the `this` - otherwise how are you willing to call the class method? You just need to cast it to the correct type.

**Update Due To Edit:**

You have this code:

```
var a = new A();
var aObject = a.Me;
```

Now what are you expecting here?
You have `a` which is from type `A`.
By using `var` you can't have multiple different return types from the `Me` geter.

Comment: I had some typos and shortcomings in my question. I've updated it so your answer doesn't really apply anymore. But thanks ;-)

Comment: @TomB. - I've updated an I have no idea what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I've added some explanation about the case, hope it makes a lot more clear about the why

Comment: @TomB. - Let me set it simple. The method Me must have a return type. If the return type is static then you have these choices. It can be "object" or some kind of common "base class". If it's a generic function, you are going to need to pass the concrete type in compile time.

So - I still to understand what you want to achieve. You want the correct casting to happen without specifying the correct type. You probably think that the var keyword will help you with doing something that cool but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the implicit definition of the variable using `var`. When you are using `var` in this case, the compiler cannot determine the correct type for `aObject` in the editor. So take the following code for example:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<TIdentifier>
{
    public virtual object Me {get {return this;} }
}

public class A : BaseClass<TIdentifier>
{
    public int X
    {
        get {return 1;}
    }
}

public class B : BaseClass<TIdentifier>
{

}

public class controller{
    public void SomeMethod(){
        var a = new A();
        var b = new B();

        var aObject = a.Me; 
        var aObjectCasted = (A)aObject;

        // the environment cannot determine the correct type for aObject
        // without compiling and running. At this time in the editor,
        // this will be recognized as a type object. It will not
        // understand aObject.X and will not compile
        Console.WriteLine(aObject.X); 

        // During run-time, this will work. aObject will be defined as type A
        Console.WriteLine(aObject.GetType().GetProperty("X").GetValue(aObject));

        // this will output A for the type
        Console.WriteLine(aObject.GetType());
   }
}
```

Without being able to modify A and B, using the GetProperty, GetMethod, etc. methods on the implicitly defined variable seems like it will be your only hope.

Update:
You can reference [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) to see the types of calls you can make on a `Type` object. It seems like you will have to do this more dynamically that desired to achieve the functionality you want. The object will not be defined correctly before compiling if trying to do it implicitly.

`var aConcrete = a.Me;` in your code will indeed return yield a type `A` for `aConcrete` at compile time, but not in the editor.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx): "It is important to understand that the var keyword does not mean "variant" and does not indicate that the variable is loosely typed, or late-bound. It just means that **the compiler determines and assigns the most appropriate type**."