# C# derived classes and properties

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I have the following classes.  For each of the control classes, I'd like to expose the data member via a property.

```
public class BasicData {}
public class AdvancedData : BasicData { }

public class BasicControl
{
    private BasicData data;

    public BasicData DataHide;

    public virtual BasicData DataOverride;
}

public class AdvancedControl: BasicControl
{
    private AdvancedData data;

    public new AdvancedData DataHide; //Hide

    public override BasicData DataOverride; //Override
}
```

If I make the property virtual, then my `AdvancedControl` class has to expose the data as `BasicData` and not `AdvancedData` (which I'd prefer).

I can instead hide the base class's property but I've read that hiding should be avoided where possible.

I want to have just one data property exposed for each Control class and I want this property to have the same name in each class i.e. `Data`.  For `BasicControl` this should be `BasicData`.  For `AdvancedControl` this should be `AdvancedData`.

What's the best way of designing my classes to achieve this?

Comment: Can't you use generics? `BasicControl<TData> where TData : BasicData`?

Comment: I would use generics have just have `Control<T> where T: BasicData` and have `Data` as `private T data;`.  `AdvancedControl` would then be `class AdvancedControl: Control<AdvancedData>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709034/does-c-sharp-support-return-type-covariance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a generic approach:

```
public class BasicData {}
public class AdvancedData : BasicData { }

public class BasiccControl<T> where T : BasicData
{
    private T data;
    public T Data;
}

public class AdvancedControl : BasicControl<AdvancedData>
{
}
```

So you don't need to override or hide the members in each derivate and still have type safety (as long as you provide the correct generic arguments for `T`).