# C# return type covariance and Liskov substitution principle

Tags: c#, covariance, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

I'm trying to understand Covariance and LSP. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709034/does-c-sharp-support-return-type-covariance) I can see C# does not support return type covariance. However [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) imposes covariance on return type.

Does it mean it is impossible to apply this principle in C# ? Or did I missunderstand something ?

Comment: You misunderstand. Return type covariance isn't the same thing as the return value being covariant. It just means you can't override the method with a different return type. It's still perfectly fine to return an instance of a derived type from a method that returns the base type - a derived type is still a subtype of the base type; LSP still fits fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# can still apply the Liskov substitution principle.

Consider:

```
public class Base1
{
}

public class Derived1 : Base1
{
}

public class Base2
{
    public virtual Base1 Method()
    {
        return new Base1();
    }
}

public class Derived2 : Base2
{
    public override Base1 Method()
    {
        return new Derived1();
    }
}
```

If C# supported covariant return types, then the override for `Method()` in `Base2` could be declared thusly:

```
public class Derived2 : Base2
{
    public override Derived1 Method()
    {
        return new Derived1();
    }
}
```

C# does not allow this, and you must declare the return type the same as it is in the base class, namely `Base1`.

However, doing so does not make it violate the Liskov substitution principle.

Consider this:

```
Base2 test = new Base2();
Base1 item = test.Method();
```

Compared to:

```
Base2 test = new Derived2();
Base1 item = test.Method();
```

We are completely able to replace `new Base2()` with `new Derived2()` with no issues. This complies with the Liskov substitution principle.

Answer (score 0):

Since return type covariance is not supported in C#, it is impossible to violate the Liskov principle when it comes to return type covariance.

Good source is this talk of S.O.L.I.D principles in C#: https://youtu.be/gwIS9cZlrhk?t=1886

Answer (score 0):

C# do have a limited support for this feature through generics and the `out` generic modifier.
(See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier)

The support is limited, because it only works with interfaces. To rewrite the accepted answer:

```
public class Base1
{
}

public class Derived1 : Base1
{
}

public interface Base2<out T> where T : Base1
{
    T Method();
}

public class Derived2 : Base2<Derived1>
{
    public Derived1 Method()
    {
        return new Derived1();
    }
}
```

In this case `Derived2` will not only implement `Base2<Derived1>` but it will also implement `Base2<Base1>`.

The principle takes effect because if you call `Method` through the `Base2<Base1>` interface it will have `Base1` return type, but if you call it through `Derived2` it will have `Derived1` return type.

Similarly you can implement parameter contravariance with the `in` generic modifier:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-generic-modifier

Note, that it is not possible to violate the principle. If in the above example you change the `out` keyword to the `in` keyword, the source will not compile, and you will get the following error:

```
Error   CS1961  Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be covariantly valid on 'Base2<T>.Method()'. 'T' is contravariant.
```

Comment: I thinks the correct phrase should be "it only works with ***generic*** interfaces" since it doesn't work with non-generic interfaces