# Declare an interface where concrete implementation has concrete types

Tags: c#, design-patterns

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    IOut SomeMethod(IIn aIn)
}

public class MyOut : IOut
{
    public string AnExtraProp {get; set;}
}

public class MyIn : IIn
{
    public string AnotherExtraProp {get; set;}    }
}

public class MyConcreteOfSomeInterface : ISomeInterface
{
     public MyOut SomeMethod(MyIn aIn)
     {
     }
}
```

Is it possible to have many classes (eg. MyConcreteOfSomeInterface, MyConcrete2OfSomeInterface, ....) implement an interface (eg. ISomeInterface) but yet have parameters of a concrete type (eg. MyIn, MyOut etc.).

I realise I could declare:

```
public interface ISomeInterface<TIn, TOut>
{
    TOut SomeMethod(TIn aIn)
}
```

but as ISomeInterface will have many methods this will not be practical. So say I need to add additional methods SomeMethod2 and SomeMethod3 then I would end up with:

```
public interface ISomeInterface<TIn, TOut, TIn2, TOut2, TIn3, TOut3>
{
    TOut SomeMethod(TIn aIn)
    TOut2 SomeMethod(TIn2 aIn)
    TOut3 SomeMethod(TIn3 aIn)
}
```

so the declaration becomes unwieldy pretty quickly.

What design pattern can I use to achieve:

1. Many concrete classes implementing an interface ISomeInterface AND
2. Using concrete parameters/return values that are implementing the necessary interfaces IIn, IOut?

There will be many methods on ISomeInteface with different types for the parameter/interface combos.

Comment: Do really need the concrete types? what is the point of the interfaces you are declaring if you don't plan on using them?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I want to ensure all the concretes implement what is defined in those interfaces *and* allow descendants to add additional properties etc.

Comment: Your final code example said that was not practical, what about doing `public interface ISomeInterface
{
    TOut SomeMethod<TOut, TIn>(IIn aIn) 
  where TOut: IOut 
  where TIn : IIn;
}`, It will be the callers responsablity to set the types of TOut and TIn when calling SomeMethod.

Comment: So now I add a second methid TOut2 SomeMethod2(TIn2 aIn) and then a third TOut3 SomeMethod3(TIn3 aIn)..... Eventually my interface declaration is going to be huge.

Comment: It might be because its lunch time here in Brisbane, but this is hard to understand what you want to do and don't want to do.

Comment: Generic Extension methods wont help you? i mean you could implement the logic once for your interface types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's simplify the problem.  Suppose we have:

```
class Animal {}
class Giraffe : Animal {}
interface IFoo 
{
  Animal M(); 
}
```

Can we then have

```
class C : IFoo
{
  public Giraffe M() => new Giraffe();
}
```

Unfortunately no.  An interface implementation must match *exactly*.

Now, you might think "hey, the interface demands that an animal be returned, and I am returning an animal, namely, a giraffe, so what's the problem?"

The answer is that there is no problem. C# could have a type system where this works, and this feature has been proposed many many many times. It's called "return type covariance", and if you do a search here you'll find many questions about it.

However C# does NOT have this feature, and so you're out of luck. The best you can do is:

```
class C : IFoo 
{
  Animal IFoo.M() => this.M();
  public Giraffe M() => new Giraffe();
}
```

And now you're good. The `IFoo` contract is explicitly implemented, and the public surface of the class has the more specific signature.

Similarly, what if we had:

```
interface IBar() 
{
  void N(Giraffe g); 
}
```

This is not legal:

```
class D : IBar
{
  public void N(Animal g) { ... }
}
```

Again, this would be perfectly sensible. IBar requires that D.N be a thing you can pass a giraffe to, and D.N is a thing that you can pass a giraffe or any animal to.  But again, C# does not support this feature.  This is called *formal parameter contravariance* and a very small number of programming languages support it.

Do a search on C# covariance and contravariance for details on what kinds of variance *are* supported by C#.

Also, note that this would not be typesafe:

```
interface IBaz 
{
  void P(Animal a);
}
class E : IBaz
{
  public void P(Giraffe g) { } 
}
```

Because you need to be able to say `((IBaz)(new E())).P(new Tiger())`.  `IBaz` says that an implementation must be able to accept any animal, so you cannot implement it with a method that only accepts giraffes.  Logically it would be safe for return types to get more specific, but formal parameter types have to get *less* specific. That's why it's return type *co*variance but formal parameter type *contra*variance, because the direction of convertibility changes in the contra case.

Comment: awesome answer. So in short not supported by C#. Any recommendations of a different approach?

Comment: @TheEdge: I gave my recommendation. Implement the interface exactly with an explicit interface implementation, and then implement the more specific / more general API as a public method on the class. Forward the interface methods to the public methods or vice versa.

Comment: Eric Lippert has previously explained a similar scenario regarding inheritance.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5709191/18192