# Generic class implementing an interface with constraints

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Given the following two interfaces:

```
public interface IFoo{}
public interface IBar
{
    IFoo Foo { get; }
}
```

The following generic class implements the `IBar` interface.

```
public class Implementation<T> : IBar where T : IFoo
{
    public T Foo { get; }
    IFoo IBar.Foo => Foo;
}
```

Why is `IFoo IBar.Foo => Foo;` even necessary and is there a more elegant solution?

Of course, I could change the property `Foo` of the `Implementation` class to `IFoo` to get rid of the generic type. But in my application, I have other classes inheriting from the `Implementation` class. Those deriving classes define a specific type for the generic `T : IFoo` argument. For example something like:

```
public class Child : Implementation<FooImplementation>
{
}

public class FooImplementation : IFoo { }
```

Comment: This is a form of return type covariance. More discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709034/does-c-sharp-support-return-type-covariance). There are also issues in the [compiler repo](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/357) and the [language repo](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/49).

Comment: Should you be able to achieve what you want by defining your `IBar` interface as `IBar<T>` and your property as `T Foo { get; }`? So in your implementation class you can do: `public class Implementation<T> : IBar<T> where T : IFoo`. This will then allow you to have a property  `public T Foo { get; }` .

Comment: @mikez thanks for the info.

Comment: @ragyaiddo I still have the same problem with your suggested approach.