# passing value to generic types

Tags: c#, generics

I have method defined like this

```
public static T FromValue<T>(int value) where T : Enumeration, new()
    {
        var matchingItem = parse<T, int>(value, "value", item => item.Value == value);
        return matchingItem;
    }
```

this is something from this [example](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/12/enumeration-classes/)

What i am doing is to call that method and pass int and get matching string from enum. So i tried doing like

```
string matchedString = MyclassName.FromValue<int>(0);
```

but this is not correct syntax as i dont know what  and how to pass to this method FromValue. Will also be nice to get examples so i can read about it and solve myself in future.

**Update**
I created class from Enumeration class in example like

```
  public  class MyClassName: Enumeration
{

    public static readonly MyClassName Dog
        = new MyClassName(0, "KL");
    public static readonly MyClassName CAT
        = new MyClassName(1, "CT");


    private MyClassName(int value, string displayName) : base(value, displayName) { }


}
```

Comment: Your `T` has restrictions, look at the `where T : Enumeration, new()`.  This means that your `T` has to follow those rules (i.e be of type `Enumeration` and have a public parameterless constructor [`new()`])

Comment: @maccettura so what to do here and what to pass ? will be nice of you really

Comment: If you expect a `string` as the return type then you need to specify that as the generic type `FromValue<string>(0)`  However that will still not work with the `Enumeration` constraint.

Comment: @Happy the tutorial you linked shows the `Enumeration` class, you are supposed to create it according to the tutorial.

Comment: @maccettura but i cant  find way to get string. If you see the Enumeration class it has FromValue method. Which i thought i can pass int value and get matching string. But i really dont know how to pass int and get string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` is not a subtype of `Enumeration`, hence, the `where T: Enumeration` constraint is not satisfied.

Thus, you need to call `MyclassName.FromValue<X>(0)`, with `X` being `Enumeration` or a subtype thereof, e.g.

```
MyclassName.FromValue<MyEnumeration>(0)
```

with `MyEnumeration` declared as

```
class MyEnumeration : Enumeration { ... }
```

Note that this will return a value of type `MyEnumeration` since you declared your return type to be the generic parameter:

```
public static T FromValue<T>(int value) where T : Enumeration, new()
              ^
```

To get a string representation, you will have to invoke `ToString()` or access a property of type string. The `Enumeration` class you linked to overrides `ToString()` as well as providing a `DisplayName` property.

Comment: The tutorial OP linked defines that class FYI.

Comment: @maccettura: I see, thanks. I have removed my second paragraph and added an example.

Comment: i need to create another class? Not sure if you understood my question. I already have created Enumeration class as in example. Then i inherited the class and created Enums. Now i want to get matching string by passing int

Comment: @Happy: *"Then i inherited the class and created Enums."* Great! Now just put the name of the "enum" you created into the brackets: `MyclassName.FromValue<TheEnumYouCreatedByInheritingFromEnumeration>(0)`.

Comment: i cannot enum like you said. Please see how i created Enums from Enumeration class in example. Can you advice further? i updated questions

Comment: @Happy: You need to add an empty public constructor to your Enumeration, that's what `where T: ... new()` means. That's a empty public constructor: `public MyClassName() { }`

Comment: i used this and it works
string d =  Enumeration.FromValue<MyClassName>(0).ToString();

but why i should call Enumeration.FromValue ? i want to call MyClassName.FromValue because eventually MyClassName has inherited from Enumeration ?

Comment: @Happy `FromValue` is a static method, and as such is not intended to be overridden in the way you are wanting.

Comment: @Happy: Unfortunately, C# does not support [return type covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5709034/87698).

Answer (score 1):

Generics can be a bit complicated to learn at first.  There are two points to bear in mind when making a method generic.

1. The generic parameter(s): (`T`)
2. The constraints, if any: (`where T:`)

The generic method in your question looks like this:

```
public static T FromValue<T>(int value) where T : Enumeration, new()
```

This generic method declaration states that you have one generic parameter `T`, and that parameter is constrained to being a type that is an `Enumeration` and it must have a public parameterless constructor (`new()`).  Constraints are useful in generics because it allows you to use generics while having a small set of rules or restrictions on it.  Maybe you constrain on an interface so you know any `T` passed in will have the members in the interface?  The possibilities are endless.

Your problem is because you are trying to use an `int` as your generic parameter, and now that I have just explained what constraints are you should know that this would not work because `System.Int32` *does not* meet the requirements.

Comment: could you give me good tutorials to be followed. Shameful to get so many negative points. TO be honest i was not even sure how i should ask question as i didnt know what is it called.