# Changing Collection type from Interface to Implementing class

Tags: c#, oop, collections, interface, ienumerable

If I have an interface with a method that returns a collection of something, is it possible to return an implementation of the collection type instead?

For example:

```
public interface IVehicle
{
    IEnumerable<Part> GetParts(int id);
}

public class Car : IVehicle
{
    List<Part> GetParts(int id)
    {
        //return list of car parts
    }
}

public class Train : IVehicle
{
    IEnumerable<Part> GetParts(int id)
    {
        //return IEnumerable of train parts
    }
}
```

If not, why not?

At least to me, this makes sense.

Comment: Did this code compile?

Comment: Strangely no. I can see use cases for this, though.

Maybe C# has different syntax to be able to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are of course free to return any implementation of an `IEnumerable<Part>` as an implementation detail of your `GetParts` method (e.g. `Train` may return a `List<Part>` easily). But the method signatures have to match *exactly* between an interface definition and a class's implementation of that method.

Here (unlike e.g. overloading) the method signature includes the return type of the method. So no, you cannot write `Car` as shown or anything similar. You are of course free to have a `GetParts` method that *does* return a `List<Part>` but that will not satisfy the interface requirement - which you may choose to provide an explicit implementation for instead:

```
public class Car : IVehicle
{
    List<Part> GetParts(int id)
    {
        //return list of car parts
    }
    IEnumerable<Part> IVehicle.GetParts(int id) => this.GetParts(id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, C# does not support covariance for inherited methods return type.

[Does C# support return type covariance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709034/does-c-sharp-support-return-type-covariance)