# Creating an interface with List<T> that allows subclasses of T

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I'm given classes `ContainerA`, `ContainerB`, `ElementA` and `ElementB`. I can't modify these classes because of very-good-reasons™ with the exception that I can add interfaces.

What I would like is something like the `IElements` interface (expect legal) as it would allow me to easily loop over the elements and read properties from the elements of either `ContainerA` or `ContainerB` without knowing which concrete implementation is actually used. There are no methods on any of the classes. For the element classes I only need to access properties implemented by the `ElementA`, exemplified by the `Id` property.

What are my options?

```
public interface IElements
{
    List<ElementA> Elements { get; set; }
}

public class ContainerA : IElements
{
    public List<ElementA> Elements { get; set; }
}

public class ContainerB : IElements
{
    public List<ElementB> Elements { get; set; }
}

public class ElementA
{
    public string Id { get; set; }    
}

public class ElementB : ElementA
{
}
```

I hope to achieve something similar to:

```
IElements container = ...;
foreach (var element in container.Elements)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Id);
}
```

Comment: If ElementA and ElementB both implement an IElement interface (or have a common base class), `IElements` could have a `List<IElement>` (or a `List<CommonBaseClass>`). You could look at something like giving `IElements` a non-generic `IEnumerable` `Elements`, and implementing it explicitly in `ContainerA` and `ContainerB`.

Comment: Do both CointainerA and B implement the same methods with the same names ?

Comment: Generics (with constraints) might also work for you here, but with no context, it's hard to suggest the correct strategy.

Comment: What are you hoping to do with this universal collection type? Add `ElementA` instances to a collection of `ElementB`? Or call methods of `ElementA` on an instance of `ElementB` without knowing which type it is?

Comment: Updated the question. There are no methods at all, only properties. I only need to access properties from the base class `ElementA`.

Comment: so expose the properties thru the interface....IElements would be Int, long, the actual properties which are on both not another list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to slice this cake, but I would consider using generics with constraints here. I'd also consider an interface (or an abstract base class) for the element object, so for example:

```
public interface IElement
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And your generic elements interface would look like this:

```
public interface IElements<TElement>
    where TElement : ElementA
{
    List<TElement> Elements { get; set; }
}
```

Making your container classes look something like this:

```
public class ContainerA : IElements<ElementA>
{
    public List<ElementA> Elements { get; set; }
}

public class ContainerB : IElements<ElementB>
{
    public List<ElementB> Elements { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can access the `Id` property of any object that implements your interfaces, for example:

```
public void DoFoo<TElement>(IElements<TElement> elements)
    where TElement : ElementA
{
    foreach (var element in elements.Elements)
    {
        // This will compile fine
        var id = element.Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably what I'll end up doing. However, I would prefer a non-generic `IElements` since I know the elements are always assignable to `ElementA` and that's all I need.

Answer (score 1):

`IEnumerable` is [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/), i.e., an `IEnumerable<SubtypeOfT>` is a subtype of `IEnumerable<T>`. Thus, the following should work:

```
public interface IElements
{
    IEnumerable<ElementA> ReadOnlyElements { get; }
}

public class ContainerA : IElements
{
    public List<ElementA> Elements { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<ElementA> IElements.ReadOnlyElements => Elements;
}

public class ContainerB : IElements
{
    public List<ElementB> Elements { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<ElementA> IElements.ReadOnlyElements => Elements;
}
```

You can iterate through them as follows:

```
IElements container = ...;
foreach (var element in container.ReadOnlyElements)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Id);
}
```

Comment: This is a reasonable solution but unfortunately the "can only add interfaces" in this case actually means that I can't actually add the implementation of the interface, the interface can only use stuff that's already there.

Comment: @Linus: Ah, too bad. You cannot even add explicit interface implementations? They won't change the public interface of your classes...

Comment: You'd need return type covariance to define `IEnumerable<ElementA> Elements { get; }` in the interface. It would be type-safe, but unfortunately, [C# does not support that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5709034/87698).

Comment: @Linus: Oh, and if the very-good-reasons™ are that the code is automatically generated, I'd like to point out that [partial classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) can be used to easily add class members to an auto-generated class.