# In C#, why can't I return a derived interface type from a function whose interface signature has the base interface type as its return type?

Tags: c#

I'm receiving the compile error:
Error   CS0535 'COITemplateWriter' does not implement interface member 'iTemplateWriter.Write(iTemplateModel)'  TemplateService
For the following code:

```
    public COITemplate Write(COITemplateModel model)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

The interface signature for the above method is as follows:

```
public interface iTemplateWriter
{
    public iTemplate Write(iTemplateModel model);
}
```

Type COITemplate implements the iTemplate interface and type COITemplateModel implements the iTemplateModel interface, so why does this code fail? Wouldn't it stand to reason that if the interface requires the method to return anything that implements iTemplate and takes as a parameter anything that implements iTemplateModel that this should compile?

Comment: That interface requires that you accept an iTemplateModel, not something derived from iTemplateModel.  The contract is that a caller can pass any iTemplateModel to this function.  That shouldn't really matter in this case, right?

Comment: The interface signature has to match exactly. You CAN return a `COITemplate` instance (assuming it implements the interface) but not change the signature. Alternatively you can make a generic interface with the `iTemplateWriter` constraint.

Comment: Thanks folks. I thought this was one of the benefits of using interfaces. Shouldn't my implemented method be agnostic of how the incoming class argument operates so long as it exposes all the required methods and properties contracted in its base interface? In my COI implementation of iTemplateWriter, I only want the Write method to accept COI models and only return COI templates. If I must just say iTemplate and iTemplateModel for the implementation, what's the point of using the interfaces anyway? That means someone could pass any model to the COI writer even if it wasn't a COI model.

Comment: But you HAVEN'T exposed all the required methods.  The interface requires that you accept any `iTemplateModel`.  Your function will not accept an `iTemplateModel` unless it hallens to be a `COITemplateModel`.

Comment: What you need is [covariant return types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns), which is coming with C# 9

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does C# support return type covariance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709034/does-c-sharp-support-return-type-covariance)

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing what you are allowed to do during run-time with what the compiler needs to know at compile-time.

This is what generics are for in C#

It looks like you want an interface `iTemplateWriter` where you want to be able to have this method `Write` that will take in any `iTemplateModel` and return any `iTemplate`

You can do this two ways:

Method 1- You can define at the interface level what type of `iTemplateModel` and what type of `iTemplate` the implementer of the interface will use:

```
    public interface iTemplateWriter<TTemplate, TTemplateModel> 
        where TTemplate : iTemplate
        where TTemplateModel : iTemplateModel
    {
         TTemplate Write(TTemplateModel model);
    }
```

doing this will allow you to define a `COITemplateWritter` that uses a `COITemplate` and a `COITemplateModel`:

```
public class COITemplateWritter : iTemplateWriter<COITemplate, COITemplateModel>
{
    public COITemplate Write(COITemplateModel model)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Use method 1 if you know at compile time what class types the implementing class needs to use**

If you need your implementing class to handle all types at run time and you do not know the type at compile-time, then use method 2:

Method 2- You can define this at the method level of what type of `iTemplate` and what type of `iTemplateModel` the method will use.  This will require all implementing classes to be able to return whatever type is passed in at runtime, which allows for more flexibility but is less structured at compile time.

```
public interface iTemplateWriter
{
    TTemplate Write<TTemplate, TTemplateModel>(TTemplateModel model)
        where TTemplate : iTemplate
        where TTemplateModel : iTemplateModel;
}

public class COITemplateWritter : iTemplateWriter
{
    public TTemplate Write<TTemplate, TTemplateModel>(TTemplateModel model)
        where TTemplate : iTemplate
        where TTemplateModel : iTemplateModel
    {
        
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it! Shouldn't `iTemplateWriter.Write` in your first example be returning `TTemplate` and taking `TTemplateModel` as an argument though?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of what COITemplate is, assuming it is not an interface, you should just need to have the function return the interface type itself.

```
public iTemplateWriter Write(COITemplateModel model)
{
   // if the "COITemplateModel" class is an iTemplateWriter you could just return that back.
   return model;

   // OR if some other object you are working with is that interface.
   return (iTemplateWrite)OfWhateverClassYouAreTrying;

}
```

Comment: It's not just the return type., it's the parameter type.

Comment: @TimRoberts, same thing.  Instead of a specific CLASS as the parameter, put the INTERFACE type (such as your "iTemplateWriter" as the INBOUND parameter.  Each subclass can handle as it deems necessary.