# Matching return types when returning an implementation of multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, covariance

How can I match return types when returning an implementation of multiple interfaces if each of those interfaces is required by counterpart interface implementations in a single function?

That's my best shot at trying to put this into words, onto the code:

```
interface IA
{
    IAA XYZ();
}

interface IAA
{

}

interface IB
{
    IBB XYZ();
}

interface IBB
{

}

class IAABB : IAA, IBB
{

}

class T : IA, IB
{
    public IAABB XYZ() { return null; }
}
```

The code above results in "T.XYZ() cannot implement IA.XYZ() because it does not have the matching return type of IAA". Same for IB.XYZ(), of course.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does C# support return type covariance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709034/does-c-sharp-support-return-type-covariance)

Comment: @Charlieface No, I justed tested the code I posted using C# 9.0 and it still won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by implementing interfaces explicitly:

```
class T :IA,IB{
    IAA IA.XYZ() { return XYZ(); }
    IBB IB.XYZ() { return XYZ(); }
    public IAABB XYZ() { return null; }
```

this will work only if IAA or IBB is an interface and not classes because you cannot inherit class IAABB from more than one base class.

Comment: While this is correct, I'm not convinced that this is what the OP wants to achieve. (I'm not criticizing your answer).

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith what OP wants is to implement 2 different methods with one method and that is not possible this is as close as you can get to the objective.

Comment: @Rafal could you please explain as to why it would not be possible to implement them as a single method. Looking at the code I see no ambiguity and thus feel like this should be possible.

Comment: @DaanVD frankly - because c# complier does not support it. It just was not implemented into the language.